# RSpec simulating calling the function argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mocking

How can I simulate calling the function argument that I'm testing with RSpec
I'm doing it like this:

```
module Module1
  def find_item(str, item_class)
    arr = item_class.find_or_initialize_by(...)
  end
end
```

Then in specs:

```
let!(:dummy_class) { Class.new { extend Module1 } }

it 'calls find_or_initialize_by' do
  item_class = double("Item")
  allow(dummy_class).to receive(:item_class).and_return(item_class)
  expect(item_class).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by)
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", Item)
end
```

And it raise an error "# does not implement: item_class"
I was trying to use class_double and instance_double but it was unhelpful.

> Failures:
>
> 1) Module1#find_items
>      Failure/Error: allow(dummy_class).to receive(:item_class)
>       # does not implement: item_class
>    # ./spec/..._spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in '

26 line: allow(dummy_class).to receive(:item_class).and_return(item_class)

Comment: hello, could you add more info on error you get?

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are going about it this way but you are not too far off.

Currently you are trying to use

```
allow(dummy_class).to receive(:item_class).and_return(item_class)
```

but `item_class` is not a method it is just a `local_variable`.

[Message Allowance](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/allowing-messages) Syntax in a nutshell is `allow(object).to receive(method_name).with(arguments).and_return(return_value)`

and [Message Expectation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/expecting-messages) Syntax is `expect(object).to receive(method_name).with(arguments).and_return(return_value)`

So maybe what you meant was `allow(dummy_class).to receive(:find_item).with(item_class).and_return(item_class)` since `find_item` is the method actually being called and `item_class` is the argument passed in but since you are stubbing the return value then the body of the method never happens.

Further more you could `allow(dummy_class).to recieve(:find_item).and_call_original` but this doesn't really serve a purpose since `dummy_class` is not a double and is already "allowed" to call its original version of `find_item`.

So lets go with the native functionality of `dummy_class` and just `allow(item_class).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by)` then the following will work.

```
it 'calls find_or_initialize_by' do
  item_class = double("Item")
  allow(item_class).to recieve(:find_or_initialize_by) #needed because it is a test double and knows nothing
  expect(item_class).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by) 
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", item_class) #used test double here to trap messages
end
```

Alternatively we can use a partial double of `Item` and skip the [Test Double](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/test-doubles) `item_class` e.g.

```
#please note this binds the test to Item existing
it 'calls find_or_initialize_by' do
  allow(Item).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by) #now a stubbed method on a partial double(Item)
  expect(Item).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by) 
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", Item) #used the partial double
end
```

[Partial doubles](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/partial-doubles) are nice because they can be verifying doubles and will make sure the `Object` actually defines that method before stubbing it.

That being said given the nature of your test and the fact that `dummy_class` is not a double (thus no need to `allow` anything) and you are not testing any return values just the call  I would suggest just using a [Spy](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies) because they are meant for just message expectations. 
This makes the test simpler,clearer and free of all dependencies:

```
it 'calls find_or_initialize_by' do
  item = spy("item")
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", item)
  expect(item).to have_received(:find_or_initialize_by)
end
```

They come in Partial Double flavor too but this is dependent on `Item` being a known and loaded `Object`:(very similar to the above but the expectation is an after effect of the call)

```
#please note this binds the test to Item existing
it 'calls find_or_initialize_by' do
  allow(Item).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by)
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", Item)
  expect(Item).to have_received(:find_or_initialize_by)
end
```

Additionally let's assume the `(...)` in `Module1` looks like `name: str` then I would suggest testing that it was called with the correct arguments as well e.g.

```
it 'calls find_or_initialize_by with args' do
  item = spy("item")
  dummy_class.find_item("item1", item)
  expect(item).to have_received(:find_or_initialize_by).with(name: 'item1')
end
```

This ensures that not only was the call made but the anticipated arguments were passed to the call.

Especially with `Module` testing of message expectation I would try to keep to Test Doubles and Spies because it makes your test independent and fast (what happens when `Item` no longer exists?)